# Use absolute paths with Jest

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, jestjs, create-react-app

I have create an app with *create-react-app*.
I have set in *.env* my **NODE_PATH=src/**
All works fine when I launch *react-script start* but when I launch *react-script test* I have an error: import is not found.
In my *package.json* :

```
"test": "jest --colors --coverage test"
```

**Edit**
It work fine with:

```
"jest": {
   "modulePaths": ["src/"],
   "testURL": "http://localhost",
   "jest": "^22.4.4"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should execute your tests with

`npm test`

instead of directly using `react-scripts` here. Jest is automatically configured while using project created by `create-react-app`.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to directly call `jest` instead using the bundling set in `react-scripts`, you have to call:

```
"test": "./node_modules/jest/bin/jest.js --colors --coverage test"
```